# Get next Item in a array using React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

> I have an array of objects like this

```
const Guide = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Dashboard',
            content: 'The dashboard is your main homepage. It will display a feed of looks...'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Discover',
            content: 'Discover allows you to find new looks, what is trending and search for looks, brands and users'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: "Upload you look, style guide and more "
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            title: "Upload you look, style guide and more "
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            title: "Upload you look, style guide and more "
        }
    ]
```

I want to be able to click a button and go to the display the data of the next object up to the last one. Currently when I click the button it just changes to the second object "Discover" and stops there, how can I ensure that it goes through with this functionality. Please excuse my grammar.

This is my state when the component mounts

```
           componentWillMount(){
            this.setState({
                index: Guide[0]
            })
        }
```

> The initial state index is  = 0, And this is my function to go to the next object

```
moveNext = () => {

   let i = Guide.indexOf(Guide[0])

   if(i >= 0 && i < Guide.length)
          this.setState({
             index: Guide[i + 1]
          })
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your state should contain the minimal information required, which in this case is the index of the item in the array. You could also use the `id`, but that would require extra work and it looks like they map directly onto the indices anyway.

```js
const info = [{
    title: 'Dashboard',
    content: 'The dashboard is your main homepage. It will display a feed of looks...'
  },
  {
    title: 'Discover',
    content: 'Discover allows you to find new looks, what is trending and search for looks, brands and users'
  },
  {
    title: "Upload you look, style guide and more "
  }
];

class Guide extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      index: 0
    };    
  }
  
  goToNext = () => {
    this.setState({ index: (this.state.index + 1) % info.length });
  };
  
  render() {
    const item = info[this.state.index];
    return (<div>
      <h2>{item.title}</h2>
      <p>{item.content}</p>
      <button onClick={this.goToNext}>next</button>
    </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Guide/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Tom, this approach is actually simpler than what I had

Answer (score 8):

Change this

```
moveNext = () => {

   let i = Guide.indexOf(Guide[0])

   if(i >= 0 && i < Guide.length)
          this.setState({
             index: Guide[i + 1]
          })
    }
```

To this

```
moveNext = () => {

   let i = Guide.indexOf(this.state.index)

   if(i >= 0 && i < Guide.length)
          this.setState({
             index: Guide[i + 1]
          })
    }
```

Explanation:

This `let i = Guide.indexOf(Guide[0])` makes you keep setting the i value to 0, thats why when you click next you keep getting the second data.

By change it to this `let i = Guide.indexOf(this.state.index)` you will set the i value to the current index, not 0.

I hope my explanation is understandable :)

Comment: Thank you @Hana, it makes much sense

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with "let i = Guide.indexOf(Guide[0])".
Try incrementing the index of the state by 1, like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
   this.state = { index: 0 };
}

moveNext = () => {

   let i = this.state.index;

   if(i >= 0 && i < Guide.length) {
          this.setState({
             index: i + 1
          });

    }
}
```

In the render method, use Guide[this.state.index] to get the data of the current index.